# Python Appengine initialize ndb model object with JSON

Tags: android, python, json, google-app-engine

I've seen countless of examples on how to encode an ndb.Model object using to_dict() and json.dumps() to a json, but couldn't find one working example on how to do the opposite: decoding the result of json.loads() to an ndb.Model object.

This is what I tried but it didn't work:

```
def post(self):
    payload = json.loads(self.request.body)
    assert isinstance(payload, dict), 'Bad payload'

    myCustomClass = CustomClass(**payload)
```

Please note that inspite of the fact that CustomClass inherits from ndb.Model and has simple properties (StringProperty, IntegerProperty...) it ALSO inherits from other classes and has repeated properties (if it changes anything to the answer... though I hope to recieve a general answer which doesn't depend on the inner of the class).

Thanks.

Comment: Did you take a look at [`populate`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_populate)?

Comment: @MihailR the method seems quite complex and I cant figure out from the documentation how to use it nor finding a good related example... could you please post a full answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [populate](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_populate).

Not really sure about the inheritance issues (you could provide a more specific example) but you would have something like this:

```
def post(self):
    payload = json.loads(self.request.body)
    assert isinstance(payload, dict), 'Bad payload'

    myCustomClass = CustomClass()
    myCustomClass.populate(**payload)
    myCustomClass.put()
```

Also, note that you should probably validate user submitted data first instead of blindly storing everything right away.